Has anyone else seen this crime movie about a detective and a gangster's wife?
It's basically a crime thriller movie which I saw on TV way back in 2000 (though it may have been produced much earlier). I didn't see it from the start; only started watching from about the middle. No A-list actors, though some of them looked rather familiar. The film stars a guy who is an undercover detective investigating a murder. In the process of the investigation, he has an affair with the wife of his chief suspect who is a crime boss. Towards the the end, he kills the crime boss by drowning him during a fight they have in a lagoon. But there is a twist in the story when it turns out in the end that the woman herself is the one that committed the murder he is investigating.
Notable scenes:

There is a scene where the crime boss has the cop strapped to a chair in his mansion and is punching him repeatedly in the face for having an affair with his wife. But he lets him go instead of killing him.
There's a scene where the crime boss shoots dead one of his underlings in an elevator because he was starting to develop a rebellious attitude.
The end scene has the cop and the woman alone in a house after the crime boss is dead. It looks like they are about to happily resume their relationship. But the cop surprises her by revealing his suspicions and getting her to confess to murder. After she admits to it, he reveals the wire he has been wearing all along. Realizing she has been set up, she brings out a gun and points it at him in anger. He manages to persuade her to "do the right thing for once" and surrender herself.


What was the time period setting of the movie 30's 50's 80's? What was the location/city...NY, LA, Chicago or some other place?

It's a modern movie. It was set in the 90s, which was the same period it was produced.

Dang it,this is rattling around in the back of my brain.  Do you have any other details? What did the woman look like?
